# Message Collector not working in Discord.js DMs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to set up a message collector in Discord.js for DMs. The bot sends a DM to the user correctly, prompting them to provide the username of the bounty target. However, when the user responds in the DM, the message collector does not seem to trigger at all, and no messages are collected.

Here's my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('bounty')
        .setDescription('Register a new bounty.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        try {
            const user = interaction.user;
            const dmChannel = await user.createDM();
            
            await dmChannel.send('Please provide the username of the bounty target.');
            
            console.log("Sent request for username in DM.");

            const filter = m => m.author.id === user.id;
            const collector = dmChannel.createMessageCollector({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000 });

            collector.on('collect', m => {
                console.log("Collector triggered in DM.");
                dmChannel.send(`Collected username: ${m.content}`);
            });

            collector.on('end', collected => {
                if (collected.size === 0) {
                    console.log("Collector ended without collecting anything in DM.");
                    dmChannel.send('No username was provided in time.');
                } else {
                    console.log("Collector ended after collecting message(s) in DM.");
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("An error occurred:", error);
        }
    }
};
```

Any insights or solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated!
[Message Content Intent is enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QCXM.png)

The problem is that after the initial DM is sent, and I respond, none of the collector's events (collect or end) seem to be firing. I've verified this with console logs, and the "Collector triggered in DM." log never appears.

Comment: how do you construct your `client`? What intents & partials have you specified?